# Prove that linear operator is a basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Prove if T : R
n → R
n is a 1−1 linear operator, and {v1, v2, . . . , vn} is a basis of R
n, then so is {T (v1), T (v2), . . . , T (vn)}.

I am not sure how I can show that. Any help or tips?

Comment: If you suppose $T(v_1) , \ldots , T(v_n)$ are not linearly independent, can you then construct a non-trivial element of the kernel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you have $n$ vectors, so it suffices to check that $\{T(v_1),\dots,T(v_n)\}$ is a collection of linearly independent vectors. So suppose
$$
a_1T(v_1)+\dots+a_nT(v_n)=0
$$
for some real numbers $a_1,\dots,a_n$. Then, since $T$ is a linear operator,
$$
T(a_1v_1+\dots+a_nv_n)=0.
$$
But $T$ is $1$-to-$1$, and we already know that $T(0)=0$ for any linear operator, so it follows that
$$
a_1v_1+\dots+a_nv_n=0.
$$
But $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is a basis for $\Bbb{R}^n$. What does this tell us about the values of $a_1,\dots,a_n$?

Comment: very interesting approach I will have to think about it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach.

Note that if $u=Tv$ then $u=T(\alpha_1v_1+\ldots+\alpha_nv_n)=\alpha_1T(v_1)+\ldots\alpha_nT(v_n)$. Therefore $\{T(v_1),\ldots,T(v_n)\}$ spans the image of $T$.

Use the rank-nullity theorem ($\dim\ker T+\dim\operatorname{im} T=\dim\Bbb R^n$) to conclude that the above set must be a basis.